# How can i fix an on_message_edit error.Is the message not supposed to be there?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey so I made this command for my logs and it seems to error every time I try to test it.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
 async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):
        channel1 = await self.bot.logs.find(before.guild.id)#code for my database
        channel = channel1["channel"]                                             
        logs = self.bot.get_channel(channel)
        embed = discord.Embed()
        embed.add_field(name="Previous message", value=before.message)
        embed.add_field(name="New message", value=after.message)
        await logs.send(embed=embed)
```

The error:

```
    embed.add_field(name="Previous message", value=before.message)
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'message'
```

I don't get what I did wrong.Is message not supposed to be there?

**Any help is appreciated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`before` and `after` are already instances of `discord.Message`, if you want to get the actual content of it simply use the `content` attribute

```py
embed.add_field(name="Previous message", value=before.content)
embed.add_field(name="New message", value=after.content)
```